# How to show only installed packages by executing "aptitude search"?

Tags: search, aptitude

After executing the `aptitude search pattern` command, I need to see only installed packages in the search result. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Add `~i` (short for `?installed`) to match the installed packages whose *name* contains `bash`:

```
aptitude search '~i bash'
```

To match whose *description* contains `bash`.

```
aptitude search '~i ~d bash'
```

To limit to the ones that are *not* installed:

```
aptitude search '!~i bash'
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually do `dpkg -l|fgrep …`. Does it count?

**UPD.**: `aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, …)'`

(But I seem to prefer `dpkg -l` anyway) ;)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to do the same with the `aptitude` command as well?

Comment: @Meysam, see the UPD.